# Delta Load - ETL process to identify updates

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a table with over 30 million rows and it takes too long to do a truncate and reload. I can do the Incremental Load using SSIS not matched output, however I am struggling to get the Delta loads where records have been updated. The Table has no Date fields so no way of checking when data was last modified.

Just wondering if anyone had come across a similar situation and how did you resolve it. I don't want load the full table as it can take 3 hours on just this one table alone!

Comment: Just to add, company won't allow CDC, triggers on table etc :(

Answer (score 0):

On the matched output, do another lookup that checks to see if the incoming row is different that the row with the matching primary key.  If it is different, do an update, if it is the same, do nothing.

I know of two ways you can check to see if the rows are the same.

1) Add a derived column to the new incoming row that creates a hash value of every column.  Then create the same hash column in your local table..compare the hashes in the lookup.

2) In the lookup, join every field...i.e. A-->A, B-->B, C-->C, etc.  Then redirect the non-matches to do an update.  This may not be possible if you have blob columns.

Number 1 is probably more efficient but harder to set up.

Comment: Hi Thanks Hank, this process may take a while as it will be comparing all the rows in the matched out in source to destination won't it?wont this take a long time and as it will go through all rows that exist thus 30 million rows which in turn will take the same amount of time as a truncate and load? wont it? or have i got it wrong? Problem is there is not way to reduce the window to look at, say as of yesterday or day before as no dates a present

Comment: Yeah, you're right...truncate and refill would be way faster...but if your source data, for example, only retains 30 days worth of data, then you would have to use an incremental / upsert methodology of some kind in order to retain historical data in your table past 30 days.

Comment: Ok, lets get creative...do you have any fields in your table that are created in numerical or alphabetical order..like maybe the primary key?  Or maybe even non-unique split key, batch key, partition key?

Comment: Yes, primary key is a guid unique identifier data type which can be sorted? Where are you going with this lol im intrigued

Comment: I was thinking that maybe you could only check the "last x rows" for changes, where x is a reasonably smaller number than 30 million.  Or another idea is you could only check the last "batch_id" for changes, which would achieve the same result.

Comment: Last x rows hey? I can't see in the data how that can possible be batched or identified as in groups.  As each row vales across attributes seem very different in meaning from proceeding rows?